# javascript .net webmethod not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, webmethod

So i got a problem with my javascript in .NET application.

```js
function koniec() {
  try {
    var name = document.getElementById('Label4').textContent;
  } catch (err) {
    name = '1';
  }
  PageMethods.UpdateItem(name);
  //alert('session ended !');
}
```

So my webmethod only executes when i got my line with alert uncommented. Otherwise its not even firing.

`<body onbeforeunload="koniec()" >`

It should execute without alert function.

Comment: You need to check if there is anything causing the javascript to throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the ScriptManager ?

If not, try adding it after the "body" tag, like this :

```html
<body onbeforeunload="koniec()">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Regards, 
ABitar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, EnablePageMethods is set to true. As i said before the webmethod is running when `alert('session ended !');` is uncommented

Answer (score 0):

It worked with me, the alert did not affect the call of the page method.

Try replacing your JS function with the code below :

```js
function koniec() {
            try {
                var name = document.getElementById('Label4').textContent;
            }
            catch (err) {
                name = '1';
            }
            PageMethods.UpdateItem(name);
            function OnSuccess(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
            function OnError(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        }
```

Regards,

ABitar